# Cheap Bluetooth receiver noise reduction

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I bought this cheap audio receiver on a whim and found it was quite noisy on the audio channel.

I know it's a piece of junk, but I thought it would be an interesting exercise to learn what was wrong in the design itself.

I've managed to clean up the audio decently well but I'm struggling to get the chirps from the Bluetooth antenna out of the audio channel.

Here's the schematic of the design:

[image]

The board is here:

[image]

What I've done is to add 10uF and 0.1uF bypass caps onto the 3.0V line, add an extra 0.1uF onto the 1.42 and 1.8V lines.  I've also added a low-pass filter to the audio out with a cutoff around 15kHz, which took the edge off the ADC noise considerably.

Purple is original, yellow is filtered:

[image: Purple is Original, Yellow is Filtered]

I'm stuck on how to get the Bluetooth digital noise out of the audio channels.

It sounds just like a UART is modulated onto the audio, you can hear the digital bits.  What I have noticed is that if I press my finger onto the Bluetooth antenna it will remove the noise completely.  I'm just not sure how to replicate that with electronics.